# JS How make that function could not be start earlier than 10 seconds after the previous launch?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function testworking(n){ 
   if(n == 1)
      testuser();
   else
        testconfig();
}

setInterval(function(){testworking(n)}, 1000);
```

*How do I make that function `testuser();` could not start earlier than 10 seconds after the previous launch?*

**P.S.:**
*an approximate algorithm:*

```
if(n == 1){
   if (first run function `testuser()` || 
         time after previous run `testuser();` == 10 seound){
      testuser();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @elclanrs becouse it need me in code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a flag using a timer:

```
var is_waiting = false;
function testuser() {
  if (!is_waiting) {
    //do your stuff here
  } else {
    alert('You must wait ten seconds before doing this again');
  }
  is_waiting = true;
  setTimeout(function() {is_waiting = false}, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
var i = 0;

function testworking(i){ 
    if(i < 10) {
        console.log(i);
    } else {
        console.log('Here is 10 second');
    }

}

setInterval(function(){
    i = (i == 10) ? 0 : i;
    i++;
    testworking(i);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're looking for, but here's something that might give you an idea.

```js
var n = 1;
var testUserInterval;

function testworking(n) {
  if (n == 1)
    testuser();
  else
    testconfig();
}

function testuser() {
  var cnt = 0;

  if (testUserInterval == null) {
    testUserInterval = setInterval(function() {
      document.getElementById("testusercnt").innerHTML = cnt;
      cnt += 1;

      if (cnt == 10) {
        clearInterval(testUserInterval);
        testUserInterval = null;
        //DO SOMETHING ???
        testuser();
      }

    }, 1000);
  }
}

function testconfig() {
  document.getElementById("testconfig").innerHTML = n;

}

setInterval(function() {
  testworking(n++)
}, 1000);
```

```html
testuser cnt:<span id="testusercnt"> </span>
<br/>testconfig n: <span id="testconfig"> </span>
```